# Schedule text message on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, messages, sms

Is there an iPhone app in the App Store which allows scheduling of text messages? For example, I would like to setup birthday messages, so I don't forget them, or reminder messages. I know of such apps, but they run only on jailbroken devices.

If there are none, is there any specific reason why no developer creates such an app? Android and Windows Phone have them, why not iOS?

**EDIT:** Apparently Apple prevents automatic sending of SMS over the SIM card (i.e. over the network carrier). But there are ways to get around this limitation without violating Apple's App Store terms.

Comment: Why can't you just set a reminder or a calendar entry for these situations?

Comment: Why not jailbreak your iPhone? Its very, very easy these days! And if you've done that, BiteSMS or Messages+ is the way to go!

Comment: Wait... you're trying to automate social interaction? Do people really think that's a good idea?

Comment: It's not about automating social interaction. Maybe I want to wish my colleague good luck for the exam, but I don't wanna get up at 5 am to do this. So I just schedule an SMS for 5 am. Or maybe it's late in the evening and I don't wanna disturb my friend while she's sleeping. Then I could just schedule an SMS which is sent early in the morning. The fact that there are many SMS scheduling apps for Android proves that there are many use cases for it.

Comment: I would love to receive an sms for my birthday from somebody I know that has died recently. Scary...

Comment: Well, most people don't die often, so your case seems to be rather rare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to now, I haven't got a satisfactory answer to this question. There really was no app on the App Store which let you schedule your text messages. And no, jailbreaking is currently no option.

So, we created our own app which solves this problem: **n8message**

(just search the App Store for `n8message`, there is also a Lite version which has no SMS credits bundled)

**Yes**, the app sends your messages fully automatically.

**No**, the app doesn't do anything that is forbidden by Apple.

Sending of **E-Mails** is free, but for **text messages** you need to buy **credits**. If you send a text message over my app, you're causing costs to us, so we cannot give away those text messages for free. There are, however, some ways to obtain a few credits for free, so you don't have to pay just to test the app.

The app does not yet work in all countries (due to some cell phone operators blocking messages), so currently it's available in those App Stores where it *is* working. For example, it does not work in the Americas, so you won't currently find it in the US or the Canadian App Stores.

Please tell us what you think about n8message, comments and feedback are very welcome.

**EDIT:** Here's some more explanation as to why the app does not work everywhere: When you send an SMS through n8message, we have to send the message in a way such that the receiver *sees your phone number as the sender*. Without that, the receiver would see something as `Unknown` or `000` or some random number as the sender.

This is done through what's known as **Dynamic Sender ID**. Unfortunately, in some countries (like the United States, Canada, China, and many more) dynamic sender IDs in SMS messages are forbidden, for various reasons. The most frequently heard reason is that dynamic sender IDs can be abused for spam, harassment, or even fraud.

That's the reason why n8message currently does not work in the US, and likely won't be working in the near future.

Comment: Um, no n8message is in the App Store I am sorry to say. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: As I said, it does not yet work in the United States and Canada (as well as some other countries), but the list of countries where it works is growing. Last week we added Australia, New Zealand, Japan, Singapore and Italy. We won't put the app online in those countries where it does not work.

Comment: Can you please explain why this isn't working on the US store and will it ever will work?

Comment: @Itzik984 See edited post.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**Launch Center**](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/launch-center-flashlight-shortcuts/id488626436?mt=8).

It won't send the message automatically (Apple doesn't allow automatic sending of SMS), but you'll have a notification that will open a new message with the contact already selected. All you have to do is write the message and press send.

Comment: Thank you, I know of Launch Center, a colleague uses it. Where did you read that Apple does not allow automatic sending of SMS?

Comment: @cheesus That would be documented in the API docs.

Answer (score 4):

The reason I want this feature is because I have employees that go into work at 4am, and I think of things I need to tell them at 11pm.  I'm not waking up at 4am to tell them they need to do something.

With a jailbroken iPhone, I use [biteSMS](http://bitesms.com) to write a text, schedule it, and my employees get it at 4am.

Comment: upvoting, but this would still be better as a comment

Comment: @AidanMiles why? `biteSMS` is a valid suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Birthday messages and reminders for yourself?  Why not use the calendar and reminder apps for that?  If you're asking for reminders others of presetting those happy birthday texts then yup, Jailbreak is the only way.  I use BiteSMS (Jailbroken).

Comment: Yes, birthday messages and reminders for others, not myself.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Future Scheduler](http://itunes.apple.com/app/future-scheduler/id515936774?mt=8) for iPhone this will help you in scheduling text messages but also emails, status update and phone calls.

Apple, does not allow third party apps to automatically send a message or email unless user confirms it. That is part of their security set up and we have to follow that.

Comment: I would have up-voted your answer if you disclosed that you are working for Appsicum, the creator of Future Scheduler. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion

Comment: @cheeesus The FAQ just says to be careful. Self-promotion is perfectly fine. "Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers"

Comment: @daviesgeek please tell me: where did Jonathanwills disclose his affiliation with Future Scheduler in his answer?

Comment: @cheeesus He said "we have to follow that." How did *you* know he worked with Future Scheduler?

Comment: @daviesgeek I'm sorry I understood that as "we, the _Ask Different_ community of Apple users and developers, we have to follow that". In his profile he mentions Appsicum, and on the iTunes page of Future Scheduler you can see that the app is from them, so I knew it from there, but there is no clear disclosure in his answer. But never mind, I didn't flag his answer and I'm not calling the police...

Comment: @cheeesus Oh. I see...I interpreted it as "we, the developers". However, do feel free to flag the answer for review.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use an app called the [Auto Sender](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sms-auto-sender/id1375015129?mt=8). It works by storing your scheduled messages on their server, and then automatically sending the message at your scheduled time. While it is not free, you have to pay for each message, it is cheaper then any of the other apps I have used. It also sends the message from a different number since it cannot send it through your phone number; but you can have a signature at the end with your name, and your actual number will always appear at the end of the message.

If you are okay with paying for it, and fine with it coming from a different number then this is something I would recommenced checking out.